# Replace inside a list of strings with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a list with strings in my script and I want to replace a value inside every string that has that value.

```
btnEdit.bind("click", function () {
    var tmplist1 = listRuntimes.val().replace(initialvalue, tbedit.val());
    listIntermediate.html(tmplist1);
    tbedit.val("");
});
```

This is my suggestion, but It won't work :S

btnEdit = Edit button, listRuntimes = list with strings, initalvalue = the original value, tbedit = a textbox with the new value, listIntermediate = listbox that displays the values.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Firebug?

Comment: Not after I updated it with the script below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$.each(listRuntimes, function(key, value) { 
  value.replace(initialvalue, tbedit.val());
});
```

Update:

```
var tmplist1 = [];
$.each(listRuntimes, function(key, value) { 
  tmplist1.push(value.replace(initialvalue, tbedit.val()));
});
```

or

```
$.each(listRuntimes, function(key, value) { 
  listRuntimes[key] = value.replace(initialvalue, tbedit.val());
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it seems that this is on the right track, but when I output my "listRuntimes" it doesn't seem to have been updated. Any idea why?